# Present view controller before initial view controller is shown

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that has the following structure:

The main view controller is a tab bar view controller that has 4 tabs.
Users can only access these view controllers when they are logged in. When app launches, it loads it's initial view controller (the tab bar one), and then I check to see if user is authenticated. If it's not, I present a login view controller.

The problem I'm having is that when app launches, it's loading the tab bar controller and from that controller it presents the login view controller, but it does so with a small time window that shows the tab bar controller's view on the screen, before the login's view. I need to directly present the login view, from the tab bar controller, but without showing tab bar controller's view in that small time interval, as it's not user friendly.

I read some answers on stackoverflow about presenting the new view controller without animation, and that's what I'm doing, but the problem persists.

I hope I've been clear enough on the issue, if you need more information just let me know.

EDIT: I'm presenting the login view controller on `applicationDidBecomeActive:` on `applicationDelegate.m`

Comment: Present the login view controller either after setting your `rootviewcontroller` as`tabbarcontroller` or `tabbarcontroller's rootview`. You shouldn't code in `applicationdidbecomeactive` to `applicationdidfinish launching`

Comment: Post the code you are using we will refractor and help you , without code we can't help you a lot

Answer (score 1):

In app delegate, In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions,

**In condition if login or not,**

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *viewController =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"your identifier"];

    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: @Gustavo Amgarten If you found this helpful then kindly accept this answer so other can easily find this.

Comment: The problem with this is that I want my root view controller to be the tab bar controller, and from that controller present the login controller. The reason for that is that I want to only dismiss login view controller if user authentication is successful

Comment: Are you using storyboard or by code to set tabbarcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

You should something like this when you have view controller in storyboard.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

FirstViewController *firstviewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];
SecondViewController *secondviewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];

firstviewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"24-around-7"];
firstviewController.tabBarItem.title = @"First";
secondviewController.tabBarItem.title = @"Second";
secondviewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"60-around-7"];
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = @[firstviewController,secondviewController];

self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
```

And in `FirstViewController`'s `viewDidAppear` you should check for user logged in or not and present view controller.

```
 BOOL loginStatus = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isLoggedIn"];
 if(loginStatus == NO){

     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
     LoginViewController *loginViewcontroller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
     [self presentViewController:loginViewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

After successful login just dismiss login view controller . If user logout just present the loginviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

CREATE NEW .H .M

(this is my code)

yourController.h and yourController.m

then open

yourcontroller.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame

{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self)
{
    NSLog(@"initWithFrame");

    [self setupPinPopUp];
}
return self;
}

-(void)setupPinPopUp{

UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
blurEffectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 66, kSCREEN_WIDTH, kSCREEN_HEIGHT-66);
blurEffectView.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                        action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[blurEffectView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self addSubview:blurEffectView];

UIView *popUpMainView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kSCREEN_WIDTH/2-150, kSCREEN_HEIGHT/2-160, 300, 270)];
popUpMainView.backgroundColor = Clear;
[self addSubview:popUpMainView];


UIView *popUpInsideView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kSCREEN_WIDTH/2-150, kSCREEN_HEIGHT/2-102, 300, 210)];
popUpInsideView.backgroundColor = White;
popUpInsideView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0;
popUpInsideView.clipsToBounds = TRUE;
[self addSubview:popUpInsideView];


UIImageView *imgCircleView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 100)];
imgCircleView.layer.cornerRadius = 50;
imgCircleView.backgroundColor = White;
imgCircleView.clipsToBounds = TRUE;
[popUpMainView addSubview:imgCircleView];


UIImageView *imgInnerCircleView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 8, 50, 50)];
imgInnerCircleView.backgroundColor = Clear;
imgInnerCircleView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"support"];
[imgCircleView addSubview:imgInnerCircleView];


UILabel *lblHeading = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, popUpMainView.frame.size.width, 45)];
lblHeading.text = @"CUSTOMER SUPPORT";
lblHeading.numberOfLines = 0;
lblHeading.textColor = Black;
lblHeading.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
lblHeading.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:21];
[popUpInsideView addSubview:lblHeading];


    UIButton *btnPhoneNumber = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, lblHeading.frame.size.height+lblHeading.frame.origin.y+10, popUpMainView.frame.size.width, 45)];
    [btnPhoneNumber setTitle:@"18002345678" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [btnPhoneNumber setTitleColor:Black forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnPhoneNumber.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    btnPhoneNumber.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18];
    [btnPhoneNumber addTarget:self action:@selector(callSupport:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [popUpInsideView addSubview:btnPhoneNumber];


UIButton *btnEmail = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, btnPhoneNumber.frame.size.height+btnPhoneNumber.frame.origin.y+10, popUpMainView.frame.size.width, 45)];
[btnEmail setTitle:@"support@vurify.com" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnEmail setTitleColor:Black forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnEmail.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
btnEmail.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18];
 [btnEmail addTarget:self action:@selector(emailSupport:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[popUpInsideView addSubview:btnEmail];

}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

[self removeFromSuperview];

}


-(IBAction)callSupport:(id)sender{

NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:@"180023456789"];
//[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];


[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber] options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success)
 {
 if (success) {
     NSLog(@"Opened url");
 }
 }];

}


-(IBAction)emailSupport:(id)sender{

 [self removeFromSuperview];
}
```

//call the method like this wherever you want to call
//IN APP DELEGATE

```
UIView *rectView;


 - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{


    [rectView removeFromSuperview];
    rectView = [[VurifyAppValidation alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kSCREEN_WIDTH, kSCREEN_HEIGHT)];
[self.window addSubview:rectView];
}
```